# Inclusão de dados pelo operador

Tags: java, mysql, conexão

Construi o código abaixo porém quando insiro os dados o sistema apresenta erro.

```
package tarefaBD;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Teste {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Pessoa inserirpessoa = new Pessoa();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        try {

        Connection conexao = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Tarefa4.2", "root", "14725800");

         System.out.println("Digite o nome: ");

         String nome = input.nextLine();

         inserirpessoa.setNome(nome);

         System.out.println("Digite a idade: ");
         int idade = input.nextInt();

         inserirpessoa.setIdade(idade);

         System.out.println("Digite o endereço: ");
         String endereco = input.nextLine();

         inserirpessoa.setEndereço(endereco);

         PreparedStatement stmt = conexao.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO pessoa(nome, idade, endereço) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?)");  

         stmt.setString(1, nome);

         stmt.setInt(2, idade);

         stmt.setString(3, endereco);

         stmt.execute();

         ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select * from pessoa");

         System.out.println("Pessoa no Banco de Dados: ");

         while (rs.next()) {

         System.out.println(rs.getString(nome));
         System.out.println(rs.getInt(idade));
         System.out.println(rs.getString(endereco));
         }

         System.out.println("Fim da leitura do banco de dados.");

              conexao.close();
              rs.close();
              stmt.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

}
```

Erro apresentado no console:

> ```
> Sat May 20 14:42:40 BRT 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
> Digite o nome: 
> rogerio
> Digite a idade: 
> 41
> Digite o endereço: 
> Pessoa no Banco de Dados: 
> java.sql.SQLException: Column 'rogerio' not found.
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:1077)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5192)
>     at tarefaBD.Teste.main(Teste.java:53)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Você está passando como nome das colunas as entradas de texto capturadas, quando deveria passar o nome das colunas como `String`, conforme abaixo:

```
 while (rs.next()) {

     System.out.println(rs.getString("nome"));
     System.out.println(rs.getInt("idade"));
     System.out.println(rs.getString("endereco"));
 }
```

O método `getString` da classe `ResultSet` espera receber o [nome da coluna](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString(java.lang.String)) como String ou o [indice da coluna](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString(int)) como inteiro. No seu código, você estava passando o conteúdo das variáveis locais `nome`, `idade` e `endereco`, recém capturadas via entrada de texto.

Um dica é separar lógica de aplicação com a lógica de modelo, para deixar seu código mais organizado e mais fácil de dar manutenção.

Answer (score 0):

O método [`getString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString(java.lang.String)) de [`ResultSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) recebe o nome (se for `string`) [ou index](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString(int)) (se for um `int`) **de uma coluna** como parâmetro, você está passando os dados que foram digitados pelo operador.

Altere o bloco de código dentro do `while` para

```
while (rs.next()) 
{
    System.out.println(rs.getString("nome"));
    System.out.println(rs.getInt("idade"));
    System.out.println(rs.getString("endereco"));
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Deu certo.